# QT, access to all data from an other Class

Tags: qt

I chose a class "A" with the QT Designer. the file A.ui  contains a TableView.
my question is:
I want not do all the processing (traitement) in Class A, I want to create another class B and thus make other treatment. This treatment is to display data in Tableview (class A).
can I access to all data from TableView from another class B.

```
//A.h
QStandardItemModel *table;

//A.cpp
table = new QStandardItemModel(10,2,this); //2 Rows and 3 Columns
tables->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Number")));
table->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Name")));
ui->tableView->setModel(table);

//B.cpp
QAbstractItemModel* tableI= ui->tableView->model();
int iRows = tableI->rowCount();
table->setItem(0,0,new  QStandardItem("100");
table->setItem(0,1,new  QStandardItem("Name 1");
```

Comment: There is no method `QAbstractItemModel::setItem`. Maybe you should use `QStandardItemModel` instead. Use `static_cast` to convert it.

Comment: it is not tableI but table which is declared in A.

Comment: QTableView doesn't have `setItem` method either. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a public member function to access your table view from another class:

```
QTableView* A::table_view() {
  return ui->tableView;
}
```

Comment: it works very well   but when i want set some data it doesn't work!!

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean by 'set some data?' Post some code.